# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function find() on boolean

Tags: php, error-handling, simple-html-dom, drupal-8

I keep getting this error when trying to capture an element from the DOM.

```
$html=file_get_html("some url here");
echo $html;
$ret = $html->find('a'); 
echo $ret;
```

I can see that the actual page is displaying from the url in `file_get_html` when I just print `$html` but the error occurs with the `find()`, no matter what element is searched for. From other solutions I have read, they state to increase the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in the simple_html_dom.php and/or remove the `strlen($str) > MAX_FILE_SIZE` from the `function str_get_html` within that file. Neither of these options have worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems from what I have read that find() won't work because it does not recognize the DOM as an object. I'm not sure I understand completely why, however I was able to throw my code into an if statement, and if the url exists then go ahead an execute the code. This seemed to work. It may only be a temporary solution, but since I have not found any others this is what I am going to go with.

```
if($html){
  $ret = $html->find('a'); 
  echo $ret;}
```